# Setting keybind / hotkey for rofi on KDE

Tags: ubuntu, key-bindings, kde-plasma

I'm trying to setup a keybind for running `rofi -show combi` without having to type it in my terminal (which works fine).

Setting up a custom shortcut via System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts does not seem to do anything:

- Trigger: `Meta+W`
- Command/URL: `rofi -show combi`

I'm running kubuntu 18.04 and rofi is installed via apt.

Tanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a workaround.

Since I'm using guake as my main terminal, I'm just making it open a new tab, show rofi and exit the tab afterwards.

```
guake -n guake -e " rofi -show combi && exit"
```

The executed command deliberately starts with a space, so it won't land in bash history.

Hope it helps others too :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's what did the trick for me:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/rofi-run
```

Paste in:

```
#!/bin/bash 
export LC_ALL="C" 
rofi -show run 2>&1 | tee /tmp/rofi-run.log 
exit 0
```

Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rofi-run
```

Then use `/usr/local/bin/rofi-run` as command/URL under `settings -> shortcuts -> custom shortcuts` ([Modifying Shortcuts - KDE Documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/khotkeys/shortcuts.html)).
Also if something fails you can now read the log under `/tmp/rofi-run.log`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the Custom Shortcuts tree, after adding your new action, don't forget to enable it by checking the checkbox and clicking Apply button.